# Verify R packages installed into docker container

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile

Does anyone have any best practices for verifying that R packages are installed into a docker container? I would like to set up my container to run on a CI service, and verify my package are installed, but as I've been building it locally, the logs seem very hard to determine what packages installed, and what did not. It would be nice to either have a CI service do this for me, or to use a simple batch script to verify the packages were installed.

Below is my current dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.R
COPY R/Makevars /root/.R/Makevars

RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    liblzma-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    ed \
    clang  \
    ccache \
    default-jdk \
    default-jre \
    && R CMD javareconf \
    && install2.r --error \
        ggstance ggrepel \
        rstan shinystan rstanarm \
        ###My pkgs
        tidytext janitor corrr officer devtools pacman
        tidyquant timetk tibbletime sweep broom prophet \
        forecast prophet lime sparklyr rsparkling \
        formattable httr rvest xml2 jsonlite \
        textclean ggthemes naniar \
    && Rscript -e 'devtools::install_github(c("hadley/multidplyr","jeremystan/tidyjson","ropenscilabs/skimr"))' \
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save this to something like `package_check.R` and then have a Docker line that runs it via `Rscript`:

```
c("tidytext", "janitor", "corrr", "officer", "devtools", "pacman", "tidyquant", 
  "timetk", "tibbletime", "sweep", "broom", "prophet", "forecast", "prophet", 
  "lime", "sparklyr", "rsparkling", "formattable", "httr", "rvest", "xml2", 
  "jsonlite", "textclean", "ggthemes", "naniar") -> chk_pkgs

suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  sapply(chk_pkgs, require, character.only=TRUE, quietly=FALSE, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
) -> ret

missing_pkgs <- sort(names(which(ret == FALSE)))

if (length(missing_pkgs) > 0) {
  warning("The following packages are not installed: %s", 
          paste0(sprintf("  - %s", missing_pkgs), collapse="\n"))
}

quit(save=FALSE, status=length(names) == 0, runLast = FALSE)
```

That will give you a missing package error with the missing list and exit the script with a non-zero exit status.

Comment: So to make this truly dynamic, should I be using an RScript to install all my packages, and simply assigning that value into chk_pkgs? Like using bash to basically take out the vector of packages put into install.packages

Comment: Aye. If you're willing to go that route (it takes time to do that) then you can make a dynamic installer & verifier. You're already doing an awesome thing by extending off of a base rocker image so that'd just be icing on the cake.

Comment: this is my "core" dilemma: when I build my docker image locally, the build log is really hard to interpret when a package finished installation, along with its deps. Like in part of my buildlog has: * DONE (rstan)

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
also installing the dependencies ‘miniUI’, ‘PKI’, ‘RCurl’, ‘RJSONIO’, ‘packrat’, ‘crosstalk’, ‘bayesplot’, ‘colourpicker’, ‘DT’, ‘dygraphs’, ‘gtools’, ‘rsconnect’, ‘shinyjs’, ‘shinythemes’, ‘threejs’, ‘xts’. So you would assume that those are deps of rstan, but rather deps based on other pks in my vector.

Comment: I've been able to build my image successfully on https://hub.docker.com/r/pgensler/sandboxr/builds/bvvskscm5htjzppwjzp6xyu/  if you want to mess around with it, but these logs are crazy difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following line to stop building the Docker image upon not finding the package you would like to install:

`RUN R -e 'stopifnot("devtools" %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])'`

Make sure to replace `devtools` with the name of the package you are trying to install.